# Reducing Polygons

Tags: polygon

I am merging several data sources into one final answer via a fishnet.  My problem is I have landcoverage with multiple attributes unioned to a fishnet.  Now I want to eliminate the smaller polygons so only the attributes of the majority polygon area per fishnet cell is representative of that entire fishnet cell.

In summary, some fishnet cells have 2 or 3 polygons within them spatially.  I want only the largest polygon to be representative of that entire fishnet cell.  Have an image that makes this all make sense but I'm a new issue so can't post it...

Thanks!

Comment: What software are you using?  Is your land cover data raster-based or vector-based?  In the mean time, check out this answer--it may help you with a zonal statistics approach to fishnets: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30492/8104